# Non type-variable argument when checking the inferred type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell. I implement the `drop` on my own.

```
myDrop n xs = if n <= 0 || null xs
              then xs
              else myDrop (n - 1) (tail xs)
```

But I call it when `n < 0`, for example, `myDrop -2 [1, 2, 3]`. It will raise an error:

```
<interactive>:23:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument
        in the constraint: Num ([t] -> t1 -> [a] -> [a])
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall t a t1.
              (Num ([t] -> t1 -> [a] -> [a]), Num (t1 -> [a] -> [a]), Num t,
               Num t1, Ord t1) =>
              t1 -> [a] -> [a]
```

Answer (score 5):

It shouldn't be possible that when you call a function with two different arguments *of the same type* one will raise a *type* error and the other will pass.  So something else is going on here.

In particular,

```
myDrop -2 [1,2,3]
```

isn't interpreted the way you expect.   It's interpreted like this

```
myDrop - (2 [1,2,3])
```

that is, subtracting the number `2` called (as a function) with the list `[1,2,3]` as its argument from `myDrop`.  In other words, utter nonsense.  That's why the type error is so weird looking.

In Haskell negative constants require parentheses:

```
myDrop (-2) [1,2,3]
```